# error accessing protected data in base class using multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

I get an error saying that the data I'm trying to access is protected in base class. I am using multiple inheritance. Shouldn't I be able to access protected data in derived class?

```
using namespace std;

class base
{
protected:
  string name;
  string age;

public:
  base()
  {
    cout<<"Enter name:"<<endl;
    cin>>name;`enter code here`

    cout<<"Enter age:"<<endl;
    cin>>age;
  }
};

class Second
{
protected:
  string gender;
  string age;
public:
  Second()
  {
    cout<<"Enter gender:"<<endl;
    cin>>gender;

    cout<<"Enter age:"<<endl;
    cin>>age;
  }
};
```

I am inheriting derived_multiple using both classes

```
class derived_multiple:public base,public Second
{
  int n;
  vector<base>P;

public:
  derived_multiple(int n,vector<base>P):base(),Second()
  {
    this->n=n;
    this->P=P;
  }
```

I get an error in this function.

```
  void print_name()
  {
    cout<<"Name:"<<P[0].name<<endl;
  }
```

Also, my both class have common data type (age) in them .If I was to use age in derived_multiple how would I specify which age am I referring to?

```
};

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  vector<base>all_base;
  base b;
  Second S;
  all_base.push_back(b);

  derived_multiple d(4,all_base);
  d.print_name();
}
```

Comment: You can access protected member of your own *object* (`this`) but not from other unrelated objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you call print_name() it's not inside something that inherits from either class because it's in an array.

```
cout<<"Name:"<<P[0].name<<endl
```

Because of this - the items in the array - even though having the data stored - the data is not accessible to the method itself; An easy solution is to have a 'friend' method that can be called by either. By adding into the base classes the following definition

```
friend void print_name();
```

Second for shared variable names - you wrap the classes in a "namespace" to get around this issue.

Using a namespace for the second issue allows classes to have the same variable names - basically the namespace specialization allows items to share the same name but still be 'different' for the compiler. By wrapping you're functions (class / whatever) you can have something like thing::AVar and otherThing::AVar. When you use namespace standard you're already doing this.

However this is just a 'messy' solution. My go to would be honestly make the SECOND inherite from the first class as it immediately solves the issue with the shared variable. (Unless of course AGE refers to different types of 'things' ).